# Launch script on login to RDS - server side

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop-services

I have a logon script that I want to be run when users login to remote desktop on my WinServer2008r2 box.  I know I can do this client-side (in the RemoteDesktopClient "Run Program" options) but would rather it be enforced server-side.  If I assign the logon script to a GPO, the script will be run whenever the user logs into their local PC.

I would like to assign the logon script to the Remote Desktop Users group, but only when they're logging into remote desktop, not when they're logging into their own system.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Use a [group policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770821.aspx) to apply this setting.

Comment: I only want the rule to be applied upon login to RemoteDesktop, not when they login to their local PC on the domain...

Comment: Did you even bother reading the page I referred you to? Create a `GPO` that enforces the `Start a program on connection` setting. It does the exact same thing as the `Start a program` section in the Remote Desktop client. See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736643%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) as well.